# How do I fix `docker no route to host` error

Tags: docker

Here is my transcript:

```
evan@evan-server:~$ docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9443:9443 --name portainer --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer-ce:latest
Unable to find image 'portainer/portainer-ce:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp 34.228.211.243:443: connect: no route to host.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I don't really know what to do as I'm quite new to docker, how can I fix this?

**System Info**
OS: Ubuntu

Thanks!

Comment: try to pull it manually, just for testing: docker pull portainer/portainer-ce:latest

Comment: or to restart docker: `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Comment: @BaktybekBaiserkeev Nope, none of the suggestions that you made worked. 

Comment: did you try pull manually with that command? `docker pull portainer/portainer-ce:latest`, if it didn't work, what did you get? The same error? @Evan Axon

Comment: @BaktybekBaiserkeev Hiya yes I did and it was the same error. I've had the problem every time docker wants to connect to the internet for a task. I'm thinking it has something to do with the firewall. You?

Comment: It should connect to the internet, and pull docker image :)) Are you running command without internet connection? @Evan Axon

Comment: @BaktybekBaiserkeev Yes it is as it can run other commands like apt-get etc